# Installing TauDEM to work with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, installation, taudem

I'm having trouble setting up TauDEM to work in the processing tools of QGIS 2.0.1.

I download TauDEM from [here](http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/downloads.html) and select "TauDEM 5.2 Command Line Executables for 32 bit Windows PC". I extract them to a directory called "C:\work\taudem".

I then go into QGIS processing menu > "Options and configuration" under TauDEM I set the "TauDEM command line tools folder" to "C:\work\taudem".

When I execute a TauDEM tool I keep getting errors saying:

> Oooops! The following output layers could not be open.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend reading the installation instruction for version 5.2 and installed the Microsoft HPC Pack 2012 MS-MPI library i.e. http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/downloads.html, point 8.

If you don't need the multi file functionality version 5.1.1 might be easier to handle and works for me in QGIS 2.0.1.

Your description sounds a bit like the algorithm is working, but not producing a correct file.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error, among others. After many hours of trial and error and searching for answers, I found that the [TauDEM 5.1.2 Command Line Executables for 64 bit Windows PC](http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/downloads.html) works for me in QGIS 2.6.0 on my 64 bit Win 8.1 machine. I couldn’t get 5.0.6 or 5.2 to work as advised in various other posts I’ve read.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using QGis version 2.6 on a windows PC and TauDEM is a plugin that you can enable by going to Processing --> Options --> Providers --> TauDEM --> Activate.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it yet, but a colleague of mine got it working in QGIS partly using the installation instruction for ArcGIS here http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/downloads.html